# Redirect warning when running s3cmd sync

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

When running s3cmd I get a redirect warning as follows:

`WARNING: Redirected to: xyz.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

The script that produces the warning is this:

`s3cmd sync /var/backups/db/ s3://xyz/database/`

I've used this script before elsewhere without this warning message. It is a problem because I use it as an automysqlbackup post run script and the warning triggers an error email notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this on github.com/s3tools/s3cmd master branch.  It was introduced in the new signature v4 code, but does not need to be a warning(), but instead lowered to info() which won't output on normal runs.

Comment: Just fyi, the version which is installed from official Ubuntu 14.04 repo (`s3cmd version 1.1.0-beta3`) still has this behaviour :)